# Unity: Using multiple timers C#

Tags: c#, monodevelop, unity-game-engine

I have multiple classes that use a countdown timer, but when I use more than one timer, the output returns the same value, not two separate values specific to their own class.

If I use one timer, everything works perfectly with no issues, it is literally just splitting those timers into separate timers.

I'm sure I have missed something simple here, but can't figure out why they are returning the same output.

**Edit:** clarity - `mfCurrentTime` and `mfTimeTravelling` return the same value, and they should return different values from each timer, but they are merging together as if there is only one timer.

They aren't acting like two separate timers, they are acting as if it is one timer

**Edit 2:** When used individually, both timers return different values, the correct values that they should be returning. It's only when both timers are running at the same time that the issue occurs.

for example:

`mfCurrentTime` will always return the current time elapsed as it is continually calling Countdown Update

`mfTimeTravelling` returns the time elapsed when the `bool _mbIsTravelling` is true.

When both classes are active, `mfCurrentTime` is correct, and when the `bool` is `true` for `mbIsTravelling` in the other class, it takes the time of `mfCurrentTime`. The issue is that they should be two completely separate timers, not one timer.

**Edit 3:** @Abion47's help lead to the discovery that everything is working as it should, I had just not included a flag for the update in the Update method. I was so fixed on the way I was calling Countdown being the issue, when the real error was a massive oversight on my behalf. I added a condition to the update, and everything is fine.

```
if(_mbIsTravelling)
{
    mIsTravellinTimer.Update();
}
```

-

*This class is using a Countdown timer.*

```
public class Level_TimeTaken : MonoBehaviour
    {
    public EndOfLevelElement UIElement;

    [HideInInspector]
    public float mfCurrentTime;
    [HideInInspector]
    public string msTimeTaken;

    private bool _mbLevelIsActive;
    private Countdown mLevelTime = new Countdown(9999.0f);

    void Start()
    {
        mLevelTime.Reset();
        _mbLevelIsActive = true;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        mLevelTime.Update();
        TimerRunning();
        UIElement.GetTimeTaken(msTimeTaken);
    }

    private void TimerRunning()
    {
        if (_mbLevelIsActive)
        {
            mfCurrentTime = mLevelTime.GetTimeElapsed();
            msTimeTaken = mfCurrentTime.ToString("#.00");
        }
    }
}
```

This class is also using a Countdown timer.

```
public class Level_DistanceTravelled : MonoBehaviour
{
    public EndOfLevelElement UIElement;

    [HideInInspector]
    public float mfTimeTravelling;
    [HideInInspector]
    public string msDistanceTravelled;

    private bool _mbIsTravelling;
    private Countdown mIsTravellinTimer = new Countdown(6000.0f);

    void Start()
    {
        mIsTravellinTimer.Reset();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        mIsTravellinTimer.Update();
        DistanceTravelling();
        UIElement.GetDistanceTravelled(msDistanceTravelled);
    }

    private void DistanceTravelling()
    {
        if (GMM.Instance.Input.ShouldLHorizontalKeyLeft() || GMM.Instance.Input.ShouldLHorizontalKeyRight() || GMM.Instance.Input.ShouldLHorizontalAxis() != 0.0f)
        {
            _mbIsTravelling = true;
        }
        else
        {
            _mbIsTravelling = false;
        }

        if (_mbIsTravelling)
        {
            // add math for working out distance so the string displays meters spooled
            mfTimeTravelling = mIsTravellinTimer.GetTimeElapsed();
            msDistanceTravelled = mfTimeTravelling.ToString("#.00");
        }
    }
}
```

and Countdown class, (a generic class for handling timers etc) is here

```
public class Countdown
{
    private float _mfCountdownTime;
    private float _mfCurrentTime;

    public Countdown(float lfCountdownTime)
    {
        _mfCountdownTime = lfCountdownTime;
        _mfCurrentTime = 0f;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        Update(Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void Update(float lfTimeStep)
    {
        _mfCurrentTime += lfTimeStep;
        if (_mfCurrentTime > _mfCountdownTime)
        {
            _mfCurrentTime = _mfCountdownTime;
        }
    }

    public bool IsComplete()
    {
        return _mfCurrentTime >= _mfCountdownTime;
    }

    public void SetComplete()
    {
        _mfCurrentTime = _mfCountdownTime;
    }

    public void Reset()
    {
        _mfCurrentTime = 0f;
    }

    public float GetTimeElapsed()
    {
        return _mfCurrentTime;
    }

    public float GetTimeRemaining()
    {
        return _mfCountdownTime - _mfCurrentTime;
    }

    public float GetProgress()
    {
        return Mathf.Clamp01(_mfCurrentTime / _mfCountdownTime);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What "value" are you referring to? What is the value currently? It's not at all clear what you mean when you say that the timer is not returning the correct value. Please state what you want the code to be doing vs what it is currently doing.

Comment: @Abion47 I have updated the post with some clarity. Thanks

Comment: @Albion47 They aren't acting like two seperate timers, they are acting as if it is one timer

Comment: They are acting like two separate timers that were started at the same time. See my answer.

Comment: @Christo - Please don't edit questions that remove content that can affect the history of the question. Each edit you made should remain in place to help future readers understand what happened in the question.

Comment: @Enigmativity ah ok. My appologies, I'm new to submitting questions here. I removed the edits as they were elaborations of the original question but provided no additional information, thinking that future readers would get confused if I had left them in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both of your scripts, you are getting the value from `GetTimeElapsed`. This value is the amount of time that has passed since the Countdown had started, which if both Countdowns were started at the same time would give you the same number.

Perhaps you meant to call `GetTimeRemaining`, which returns a value that takes the total time given into account? Or maybe `GetProgress`?

Comment: @Albion47 although the timers start at the same time, they call .update() at different times, so their end result will be different even if they start at the same time.

Comment: @Christo I'm not sure how Unity does it, but in general, game engines will call `Update` on all of the game objects as part of the same pass. During this pass, `Time.deltaTime` will have the same value in every call to any `Update` method. As such, both timers will be incremented by the same amount, regardless of when in the overall pass they are updated.

Comment: @Christo Also, my name is not Albion.

Comment: my appologies for the name typo. Yes I understand the Update, but if I run them seperately, they fully function and return the values that they should as they are calling Countdown Udpate at different times (which works really well). The issue is when I run two at the same time.

Comment: @Christo When in your game are the timers _started_?

Comment: they are both reset on start, and one "starts" when the bool _mbLevelIsActive is true. The other starts when _mbIsTravelling is true. I have added a debug to each value, and they act as they should do, and return the correct values. The issue is when I run both at the same time. I have updated my question to add clarity to this. I need each class to have it's own timer, that isn't effected by the other timer.

Comment: @Christo Then like I said, both instances of `Countdown` are started at the same time and are updated with the same value, so it would be an error if they _didn't_ have the same elapsed time values. There is nothing in your `Level_DistanceTravelled` class that prevents that class' `Countdown` from updating - it is not prevented by your `_mbIsTravelling` flag. I think the issue might be that you are confusing your `Countdown` objects with your `float` objects.

Comment: @Christo Here's an experiment to try. When your `Countdown` objects are first instantiated, assign them a random number. Then when you get their respective time values, check them against that number to see if they are truly one and the same timer.

Comment: Interesting, so surely `Level_DistanceTravelled` Countdown should return the same value as `Level_TimeTaken` Countdown when ran sperately, unless `Level_TimeTaken` is forceably updating `Level_DistanceTravelled` Countdown. Which is the issue im having. My original question is about splitting these up so they are two seperate Countdown timers, which is where I'm still stuck.

Comment: @Christo They *are* two separate Countdown timers that *are* updating at the same time. Look at the Update function in `Level_TimeTaken`. It says right there: `mIsTravellinTimer.Update();`. That code is _not_ conditional to any bool value. It runs on every Update, which from what you are saying is not what you want.

Comment: yes they return the same number, which is not what I want it to do, I want it to return a seperate number. I want it to be two seperate Countdown timers, not the same timer

Comment: @Christo Just because they return the same number doesn't mean they are the same timer.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to stop from happening, and I don't know how. I understand they are updating each other, and I now understand they are different timers, how do I stop them from updating each other, so that they only update themselves.

Comment: @Christo So you don't want the timer in `Level_TimeTaken` to update when `_mbIsTravelling` is false, correct?

Comment: @Christo Then code it that way, dude. Look at your script. `mIsTravellinTimer.Update();` is in the Update function free to run whenever.

Comment: They should be handled seperately

Comment: How could I be soo stupid... I honestly thought I was calling a new countdown timer incorrectly and was ripping my hair out, and the issue all along was I hadn't added a flag to the update. I'm really sorry I completely overlooked this. Thank you for your help! What a massive undersight on my part!

Comment: my appologies for wasting your time when the issue was extremely trivial and I should have stopped fixating on the Countdown being wrong when the issue was my own fault for overlooking the Update. Less coffee... more sleep. I have marked your answer as correct as you found my silly error. Thanks